# Twilio autopilot redirect not working properly

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

Im having a problem in getting Autopilot redirect to work

After redirecting to my POST url it stops saying anything.

Below is my code:

```
{
    "actions": [
        {
            "collect": {
                "name": "password_reset_collect",
                "questions": [
                    {
                        "question": "I will perform password reset to your account. Do you wish to continue?",
                        "name": "continue",
                        "type": "Twilio.YES_NO"
                    }
                ],
                "on_complete": {
                    "redirect": "https://88fb4b1a.ngrok.io/Voice/Post"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "remember": {
                "action_query": "password_reset"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

and in my POST url it returns JSON result using return Content() as follows

```
var response = "{\"actions\": [{\"say\": {\"speech\": \"Thank you! Have a good day\" }},{\"listen\": true }]}";

return Content(response, "application/json");
```

result:

```
{
 "actions": [
  {
    "say": {
      "speech": "Thank you! Have a good day"
    }
  },
  {
    "listen": true
  }
 ]
}
```

It never say what I specified in the  on JSON and the call end
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A better flow might be having a separate task that says `Thank you! Have a good day` and have your POST webhook just redirect it to that task like `{"actions":[{"redirect": "task://end_greet_task"}]}` where `end_greet_task` just says your message.

Comment: No actions are executed after the redirect. 
Twilio uses the results from the redirect as the next set of commands.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'd try putting `Remember` before `Collect`, as mentioned on the [Actions docs page](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/actions).

Comment: thanks but that is not the issue. my task in autopilot is working and is redirecting to my POSt url and it returns a actions json. the problem is its not responding anything

Comment: I only experience this when my task action has collect with redirect action

Comment: After redirecting to the Post URL, do you hear the `Say`? Have you tried redirecting to a Twilio Function instead?